# Print largest number on file code using python

Tags: python

Write a program named readfile.py that uses a loop to read and process mynumbers.txt. The program should output all of the integers, one per line, with no blank lines between each line. This program should also output the largest random number that was on file.

I have this so far:

```
infile = open('mynumbers.txt','r')

for line in infile:

  print(line,end='')
infile.close()

print('The largest random number that was on file is')
```

Everything works but it wont give me largest random number that was on file. Other site said this was broken but its not. It will pull all the integers from the text file. At the end it also needs to print 'The largest random number that was on file is' but I need that number to show.

Comment: Give this is a homework problem. This is what you did: 1) Opened the file, 2) looped through the file, 3) printed all the contents, 4) closed the file, 5) printed a string (no actual useful data). Fix it from there. What you're being asked and what you provided do not match.

Comment: You just need to keep a variable containing the largest number so far and update it on each loop if you find a larger number. Then print it as part of the final print statement in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by random largest number? If you have numbers in the file and you want to print the largest number from those numbers, that's not random. Do you just want to print the largest number, that's it?

Comment: 1) Read some docs 2) Read your code 3) think about what it does **Hint:** How can you get that number to show?

Comment: Joe, I think your close. The text file has random number. One of the programs loads anywhere from 6 to 12 random number to that file. Im trying to figure out how to grab the largest number from that file and have it show on the Python shell. Im sorry guys, I am a huge noob on this and yes this is for a homework assignment. I have everything else figured out except for this.

Comment: @BillMatias See my answer. Try not to use the extra hint, and read the documentation. That's a biggie. Read the documentation.

Comment: Search for numbers in the string, cast to floats, use the `max` function.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, since this appears to be a homework problem we will just lead you on the correct path.

You correctly opened the file, looped through it, printed each line, and closed the file.

(If the problem wants you to print each number on a new line then you might want to review your code regarding the print function)

However, you did not keep track of the size of the numbers that you are iterating through in any way.

*Hint: Use conditional statements, comparison operators, and a variable or use a list.

Conditional Statements: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comparison Operators: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Lists: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

You'll have to go from here.

*Note: Look into the With statement: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: The text file has random number. One of the programs loads anywhere from 6 to 12 random number to that file. Im trying to figure out how to grab the largest number from that file and have it show on the Python shell. The rest of the program retrieves the number from the text and prints them in Python. Im sorry guys, I am a huge noob on this and yes this is for a homework assignment. I have everything else figured out except for this.

Comment: @Bill Matias Since you appear to still be having troubles with this I will tell you the general idea of how to do it but you must be the one to write the code, otherwise what is the point of the experience?
As you iterate through the file, keep track of the numbers that you are printing and check to see if the current number is larger than a number stored in a largest_value variable. If it is, store the current number in that variable. When the loop completes, the answer will be stored in the variable. Now go write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hints

- Run your code.. does it generate an error?
- Read this documentation: [python built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)
- Is there a function that can do it for you?

You cannot just simply use pure english and do `for line in file`, you must use this code:

```
infile = open('mynumbers.txt','r')
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    ...
```

`.readlines()` turns all the lines into a list so you can iterate over them.

Extra hint if you've **read the documentation and cannot figure it out**:

http://freetexthost.com/y422jtddfl

Answer here:

http://freetexthost.com/biylxaqt2y

EDIT: improved answer in URL. Old answer here: http://freetexthost.com/12yermhmfn

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also print the largest number in your file, you just have to add this to your code under your other `print`:

```
print max(infile)#Python2
print (max(infile))#Python3
```

That is if you only have numbers in your file.